# Jetpack Compose view not drawing when coming back to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

Using a Compose view that inherent from AbstractComposeView
inside an XML ui code of a fragment
Knowing that this fragment is part of a navigation graph (Jetpack navigation)
When i press the back button going back to my fragment, the compose view just **disappeared**.
It's only drawing for the first time i open the fragment.

Bellow view code

```
class ProgressComposeView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AbstractComposeView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var steps = mutableStateOf(0)
    private var currentStep: Int = 0
    private var windowWidth: Int = 0

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        ProgressView(steps.value, currentStep, windowWidth)
    }

    fun setData(steps: Int, currentStep: Int, windowWidth: Int) {
        this.steps.value = steps
        this.currentStep = currentStep
        this.windowWidth = windowWidth
    }

}


@Composable
fun ProgressView(totalSteps: Int, currentStep: Int, windowWidth: Int) {

..... }
```

Comment: Could you provide the Fragment's code? Maybe you need to call the `setContent` in the `onViewCreated` method.

Comment: have the same problem, the setContent{} code block is placed in onViewCreated method - it does not help

Comment: @Rob i answered this , please check my answer

Comment: actually using view pager(FragmentStatePagerAdapter) instead of manually adding fragments with fragmentManager solved my problem @Oussaki

Answer (score 4):

Solution :

You have to call `.disposeComposition()` on your `ComposeView`

In your onResume() function

Example :

```
 override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    binding.composeHeader.disposeComposition()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Oussaki's answer is correct. However, you might also try your luck with one of the [`ViewCompositionStrategy`s](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/compose-in-views#composition-strategy) which take care of disposing for you.

Specifically, `DisposeOnLifecycleDestroyed` or `DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed` should be able to help you in your case.